# chart.js how to draw arrow instead bar

Tags: chart.js, draw

What is the easiest way to draw an arrow instead of the bar?

I have tried this method, to add an image in every point, but the arrow is not responsive and I can't set the size of each arrow image.

```
// Variables 'sun' and 'cloud' are created before with `new Image()`

Chart.pluginService.register({
    afterUpdate: function(chart) {
        chart.config.data.datasets[0]._meta[0].data[7]._model.pointStyle = sun;
        chart.config.data.datasets[1]._meta[0].data[2]._model.pointStyle = cloud;
    }
});
```

And will give you [this result](https://jsfiddle.net/0cjxp0as/).

I have achieved it here [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/qk5t06h1/2/).